# Lantronix ETS16P: Escape Sequence

Tags: terminal, serial-port, rs232, terminal-server

I have an Lantronix ETS16P serial terminal server which I have configured to login via telnet and have access to the serial port of my servers, routers, switches. I have done this by configuring a menu as follows:

```
telnet lantronix 7000
# userpassword
Local> Set Privileged
Local> SHOW MENU

DEFINE MENU TITLE "Lantronix Console Server:"
DEFINE MENU 1 "Server: main" "connect local main"
[...]
DEFINE MENU 11 "-Show sessions" "show sessions all"
DEFINE MENU 12 "-Next session" "fg"
DEFINE MENU 13 "-Close session" "close"
DEFINE MENU 14 "-Logout" "close;logout"
DEFINE PORT 0 MENU ENABLED
```

For each port I have set the local switch to be `^B` (CTRL+B) and break control to be Local, e.g.:

```
Local> SHOW PORT 2

Port 2 : Username:                     Physical Port 2 (Idle)

   Char Size/Stop Bits:         8/1    Input Speed:                57600
   Flow Ctrl:               Cts/Rts    Output Speed:               57600
   Parity:                     None    Modem Control:               None

   Access:                   Remote    Local Switch:                  ^B
   Backward:                   None    Port Name:                   main
   Break Ctrl:                Local    Session Limit:                  4
   Forward:                    None    Terminal Type:             Ansi()

   Preferred Services:        (Lat)
                           (Telnet)

   Authorized Groups : 0
   (Current)  Groups : 0

   Characteristics:  Loss Notify  Telnet Pad
```

I used a configuration like this (I think) for years and could get back to the Lantronix menu with CTRL+B after connecting to a port.

However, then the lantronix randomly lost its configuration and since then CTRL+B does not work any more. I do not know exactly which config is required and what is wrong.

What needs to be set so that I can use CTRL+B to return to the lantronix menu? (or command line after using `connect local main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user guide seems to be a bit unclear on this. It is not the ports to be accessed with the `connect local` command which need to have the control sequence set but the port on which the user connects. For a telnet session, this is port 0. However, this port does not really exist but only as a "template". Hence, Define must be used:

```
DEFINE PORT 0 LOCAL SWITCH ^B
```

Then the ETS must be rebooted, since `Define` does not apply the settings (and can't because it is not an instantianted port):

```
INITIALIZE DELAY 0
```